CLLocationCoordinate2d does not conform to 'PersistentModel' SwiftData
Trying to migrate to SwiftData and I get this error:

Referencing instance method 'setValue(forKey:to:)' on 'Array' requires that 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' conform to 'PersistentModel'

@Model
class Stage: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var route: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
    var length: Double
    var text: String
    var completed: Bool

    
    init(id: String,
         name: String,
         route: [CLLocationCoordinate2D],
         length: Double,
         text: String,
         completed: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.route = route
        self.length = length
        self.text = text
        self.completed = completed
    }
}

New at Swift also and I've tried to understand conformance to 'Codable', which I believe is the underlying issue, but I don't understand how to implement that.

Figured it out.
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude
        case longitude
   }

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.init()
        latitude = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .latitude)
        longitude = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .longitude)
   }
}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Encodable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(latitude, forKey: .latitude)
        try container.encode(longitude, forKey: .longitude)
   }
}

